# Must declare the scalar variable error in executing procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't understand the definition of scalar variables in SQL. Please help to solve this issue. I am facing an issue to use `@minb` variable to execute the procedure `getMinimumBalance`. I am receiving the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable.

```
CREATE DATABASE ATM
go 

USE ATM
go

CREATE TABLE [User]
(
    [userId] int PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [phoneNum] varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    [city] varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
go

CREATE TABLE CardType
(
    [cardTypeID] int PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] varchar(15),
    [description] varchar(40) NULL
)
go

CREATE TABLE [Card]
(
    cardNum Varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    cardTypeID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CardType([cardTypeID]),
    PIN varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    [expireDate] date NOT NULL,
    balance float NOT NULL
)
go

CREATE TABLE UserCard
(
    userID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [User]([userId]),
    cardNum varchar(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Card](cardNum),
    PRIMARY KEY(cardNum)
)
go

CREATE TABLE [Transaction]
(
    transId int PRIMARY KEY,
    transDate date NOT NULL,
    cardNum varchar(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Card](cardNum),
    amount int NOT NULL
)


INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (1, N'Ali', N'03036067000', N'Narowal')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (2, N'Ahmed', N'03036047000', N'Lahore')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (3, N'Aqeel', N'03036063000', N'Karachi')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (4, N'Usman', N'03036062000', N'Sialkot')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (5, N'Hafeez', N'03036061000', N'Lahore')
GO


INSERT [dbo].[CardType] ([cardTypeID], [name], [description]) VALUES (1, N'Debit', N'Spend Now, Pay Now')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CardType] ([cardTypeID], [name], [description]) VALUES (2, N'Credit', N'Spend Now, Pay later')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1234', 1, N'1770', CAST(N'2022-07-01' AS Date), 43025.31)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1235', 1, N'9234', CAST(N'2020-03-02' AS Date), 14425.62)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1236', 1, N'1234', CAST(N'2019-02-06' AS Date), 34325.52)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1237', 2, N'1200', CAST(N'2021-02-05' AS Date), 24325.3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1238', 2, N'9004', CAST(N'2020-09-02' AS Date), 34025.12)
GO

INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (1, N'1234')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (1, N'1235')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (2, N'1236')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (3, N'1238')
GO
Insert  [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (4, N'1237')

INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2017-02-02' AS Date), N'1234', 500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2018-02-03' AS Date), N'1235', 3000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2020-01-06' AS Date), N'1236', 2500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2016-09-09' AS Date), N'1238', 2000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2020-02-10' AS Date), N'1234', 6000)
GO

create procedure [dbo].[getMinimumBalnce]
@minBal float OUTPUT
as 
begin 
    select min(balance)
    from [Card]
End


declare @minB float


execute getMinimumBalnce
@minBal= @minB OUTPUT
go
```

Change  declare as MiniBalance to declare @minB float and also removes go but still facing issue

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server - please correct your tags. And please quote the entire, exact error message, not a summarised version. And I suggest you **do not** want to be using a `float` datatype. That is for scientific uses only and does not store an accurate number. You probably want `decimal`.

Comment: Your problem is `declare @minB as MinBalance;
GO` - go is a batch separator, anything declared before it goes out of scope. Remove `go` and it will work.

Comment: GO is a batch separator and divides code into separate units of compilation. You declare your variables for your procedure execution in one batch - but those "disappear" when that batch ends. Simply remove the line with GO that separates the variable declarations from the procedure execution.

Comment: @DaleK GO is NOT a statement terminator.

Comment: without go still facing the same issue

Comment: You need 'go' after your stored procedure declaration. Personally I create my SPs as a totally separate exercise (and in a different query window) from where I am trying to run them. After all, you only want to create it once, but you want to run it multiple times. And then you may want to alter it, but not recreate it.

Comment: Okay, I understand.... But can you tell me what actually it means about the scalar variable?

Comment: You declare `@minBal` in your procedure as `OUTPUT` parameter, but you never assign any value to it

Comment: "But can you tell me what actually it means about the scalar variable?" I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: Actually, I am asking about the scalar variables definition in SQL.

Comment: Right, but what are you asking? What do/don't you understand? They are variables pretty much like any other programming language.